# What is the function of the adverb “gleich” here?

Tags: meaning

> Beim kleinsten Pieps machst du dir **gleich** ins Höschen!
>
> =? "You get worked up over the tiniest things!"
>
> Or more literally: "You wet (in) your pants over the tiniest things!"

I understand that the adverb “gleich” can be used for emphasis with the meaning of “right/just”, but in this specific sentence:

Does “gleich” serve as a ***zeitlich*** emphasis?

> "You (***right away / immediately***) get worked up over the tiniest things!"

Or, does “gleich” serve as a ***räumlich*** emphasis, placing emphasis on  the preposition "in"?

> "You wet (***right / just***) in your pants over the tiniest things!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is more used in timely manner in combination of a jumpy person. As you already wrote **"immediately"**.

Like:

As soon as something happened, you pee in your pants.